# How does one enter the locked stairwells in Halls of the dead in Falskaar

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

So I went into the halls of the dead, had an epic battle with a dozen Deathlords after picking up the potion from the altar..and now what? There are 2 cage covered stairwells there leading down with doors that don't open, a section of floor with fire jets..and no switch or chain or door or anything else to activate these. How do I get inside?

Comment: The doors forward opened up immediately after picking up the potion for me. Are you using any mods that could affect the doors?

Comment: Are these the same doors set into the cages? There's an 'open door' option when I go near them but it does nothing.

Comment: The cage doors opened up when I picked up the potion. All of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by toggling no clip mode(console command `tcl`), walking through the wall and returning, after which the gate was open.

Answer (score 2):

It’s been seven years it looks like since this thread was active but I stumbled across it trying to solve the same problem. There’s literally a lever on the side of the pedestal where you pick up the note. Hopefully that helps somebody else when they stumble across it, too.

Comment: The game's been updated quite a bit since I first asked this, there was no lever or anything else when I first played it.

Answer (score 0):

The doors should open when you pick up the potion, mine didn't but I reverted to the closest save and the doors opened. Xbox 360